# Build cmake on OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, cmake

I am trying to build cmake from source on OS X 10.10, it stops at 17% and output error
"strerror_r MUST be either POSIX, glibc or vxworks-style"
 Is it a bug in cmake source code?

Comment: You can build it using either macports or homebrew. These usually take care of dependencies and patches in a good manner.

Comment: Is there a way without using third party environment?

Comment: It should compile but I don't know why it fails. I use nginx, postgresql and other tools on my mac and have used macports to install these rather than compile them one by one and manually install dependencies. According to cmake's webpage there are precompiled binaries. Any particular reason you need to compile it manually?